# localhost:8000 ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: php, apache, localhost

Recently my localhost:8000 stop working. I didn't change anything. This is my error:[image]

I work with php-mysql-apache2 other local host is working fine. 
What can be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use web server by PHP:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/built_in_web_server.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are on linux check if your apache service is on.

```
sudo service httpd status
```

Comment: httpd.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)

Comment: you need to activate your apache

Comment: Apache is working because my phpadminer is going well.

Comment: Ok need to listen on port 8000. Follow this [link](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1184613). That should help you out